# Prisma error parsing attribute "@relation"

Tags: prisma

I'm currently grappling with a challenge in my Prisma data model and would greatly appreciate your insights and expertise in overcoming it.

Here's a snippet of my schema:

```
model TextContent {
  // .. other fields
  StoreName        Store[]       @relation("store_name")
  StoreDescription Store[]       @relation("store_description")
}

model Store {
  // .. other fields
  nameId        Int?
  name          TextContent?  @relation("store_name", fields: [nameId], references: [id], onDelete: SetNull)

  descriptionId Int?
  description   TextContent?  @relation("store_description", fields: [descriptionId], references: [id], onDelete: SetNull)
}
```

My primary question revolves around configuring the Prisma schema to ensure that when a `Store` record is deleted, the associated `TextContent` records (pertaining to name, description, and slogan) are either automatically deleted or properly disassociated.

However, upon attempting to implement cascading deletion by changing the `onDelete` option in `TextContent`:

```
StoreName        Store[] @relation("store_name", onDelete: Cascade)
```

I encountered the following error:

```
Error parsing attribute "@relation": The relation field `StoreName` on Model `TextContent` must not specify the `onDelete` or `onUpdate` argument in the @relation attribute. You must only specify it on the opposite field `name` on model `Store`, or in case of a many-to-many relation, in an explicit join table.
```

I chose the `"store_name"` approach due to multiple one-to-many relations with the same table.

Any advice or guidance on resolving this error and achieving the desired cascading deletion would be immensely appreciated.

Thank you in advance for your assistance!